# Javamail on Android Studio, issues with Message.getContent()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jakarta-mail

I am having some pretty strange issues when calling the Javamail Message.getContent() command on Android Studio.

My app requires the display of email contents, which I know will always be plain text, so I set the content of a text view object in the following way:

```
contentTextView.setText(message.getContent().toString())
```

However this does not set the text on the app display. The text simply doesn't change.

What is strange is that if I set the text as the Sent date instead:

```
contentTextView.setText(message.getSentDate().toString())
```

It works exactly as expected. Even more puzzling, if I simply try to print the message to the console:

```
System.out.println(message.getContent().toString())
```

It fails to print. This is despite the fact that running the same command in command prompt, on the same email, works fine.

So it seems to me that Android Studio is not happy with the message.getContent() command. But my hours of debugging have not figured out why.

Comment: Are you using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android)?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: I wasn't but am now - I didn't realise there was a separate version for Android - thanks! I finally solved the problem anyway, turns out I was closing the folder/store before calling getContent() without realising, which explains why getSentDate() worked, since from my understanding the content of the email isn't retrieved until getContent() is called, whilst the header data is retrieved once getMessages() is called.

Comment: The header information isn't retrieved until needed, or unless you use Folder.fetch.